# Crashing the application from within a Q promise instead of propagate a rejection through a chain of promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

So basically the problem is that Q swallows my exceptions that are not meant to reject the promises, but to crash the application as early as possible, so that I know what exactly is broken.

I know that I can (and probably should) use the `done` method at the end of the chain, but it's really a pain in a butt to keep track of the chain ends. And it doesn't help much because it doesn't prevent Q from catching it and once cached the exception looses it's stack trace.

Is there a way to crash early when the exception is thrown rather than propagate the rejection up the chain hoping there is done at the end of it?

Comment: If you have exceptions that should never be handled, why not explicitly terminate?

Comment: @SLaks, that's the problem, I wish I could explicitly terminate, but throwing from inside a promise handler execution context all exceptions get caught and explicit termination is not possible, or at least I don't know how to do it

Comment: So you're complaining because of a major feature of promises - "throw-safety"?  Then, stop using promises.  This is how they're supposed to work.

Comment: Exactly. Swallowing all exceptions is a bad practice. Deciding for the developers what is right for them without giving a choice is another bad practice. Separating exception handling from handling valid data is what prevents promises from being true functors and monads. So yeah, what you call throw safery is a just an example of bad design. I indeed need to find or develop something else that does things right way.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I humbly disagree, your library code deciding for _my_ application that it should terminate if your library failed is a _huge_ violation of separation of concerns - your code doesn't have the broader view and should not get to make these decisions. This is exactly like synchronous code. Please [read this thread](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/51) for a discussion of the topic.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, quite contrary, my library is not going to decide for you what you want to do with exceptions, my library will give you an option to propagate a rejection or fail with a crash immediately, it's always nicer to have a choice rather than not have one

Comment: The user can crash immediately by using a modern promise implementation and not handling the rejection explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Right, so my PR for Q just got merged, you can now do this:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(err, promise){
    throw err; // terminate with error if a `.catch` is not attached
});
```

Which will cause the process to exit whenever an exception is not explicitly handled (via `catch`). This ends a long saga of debugging issues with promises. Gone are the days of `.done`.

Just make sure to get Q 1.30, released 6 minutes ago :D

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `process.exit(1)` (or any other exit code), which will terminate the process immediately without throwing an exception.

Comment: it's from the browser, you can't terminate it

Comment: @AlekseyBykov: Then what do you want to do?

Comment: i want the browser to report an uncaught exception using its standard mechanisms for that (usually a dump to the console with a stack trace)

Comment: in my own code that would have been an option, but i have code that is a black box that just throws, i cannot put console.error in it, of course i can wrap it in my own try/catch but this is a lot of hassle for something that otherwise would have been working without any extra efforts, i got your point, i need a straight solution, i am not looking for workarounds

Comment: and a straight solution doesn't exist, so my bad luck: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/684

Comment: @AlekseyBykov support is coming for better instrumentation for promises (Domenic is working on it) if you use other promise libraries (like bluebird) you have configurable error handling and typed catches that let you fix this easily.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to defer the actual execution of the promise callback. This will force the function into the event queue and the calling function will not catch this error.

An example:

```
try {
    setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error('Not caught');
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is much better than just using `.done`.